# Frage zu mehreren Mehrzahlformen

Tags: declension, weak-declension

Letzte Woche ist es mir aufgefallen, dass mehrere Wörter mehrere Mehrzahlformen haben und ich weiß nicht, wann die eine oder die andere verwendet werden sollte.

Zum Beispiel:

> Die Angestellte fordern eine Lohnerhöhung.

oder

> Die Angestellten fordern eine Lohnerhöhung

Beziehungsweise:

> Zwei Bekannte von mir wollen heute Abend ausgehen.

oder

> Zwei Bekannten von mir wollen heute Abend ausgehen.

Beide Wörter haben zwei Mehrzahlformen die im Duden stehen, und ich weiß nicht, ob es einen Unterschied zwischen den beiden Formen gibt. (Es ist wichtig im Kopf zu behalten, dass die beiden Mehrzahlformen mit einer *-n* Endung laut Duden nicht ausschließlich im Dativ, sondern auch im Nominativ und im Akkusativ existieren.) Könnte jemand mir bitte den Grund dahinter erklären? Ich konnte gar nichts darüber im Internet finden...

Answer (score 4):

Das ist ein Missverständnis, in beiden Fällen sind das keine austauschbaren Pluralformen.

Es handelt sich um unterschiedliche Fälle im Plural, siehe [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Bekannter). Nur *Die Angestellten* bzw. *Zwei Bekannte* ist richtig.

Es ist kompliziert, weil je nach Vorhandensein eines Artikels die starke oder schwache Deklination angewandt werden muss. (Das gilt auch für den Singular.)

Comment: Danke schön. Also wenn ich das richtig verstehe, dann sind die folgenden Sätze richtig geschrieben wegen der starken oder schwachen Deklination, beziehungsweise, ob das Substantiv bestimmt oder unbestimmt ist: "Angestellte fordern eine Lohnerhöhung / die Angestellten fordern eine Lohnerhöhung / zwei Bekannte von mir wollen rausgehen / Bekannten von mir wollen rausgehen".

Comment: @spencert Ich kann in den Beispielen drei und vier keinen Unterschied der Randbedingungen erkennen. Deswegen muss es in beiden Fällen *Bekannte* heißen.

Answer (score 3):

Das sind substantivierte Adjektive, und sie werden wie Adjektive dekliniert.

> Angestellte Menschen fühlen sich weniger frei als selbständige.
>
> Die angestellten Menschen haben sich organisiert.
>
> Ein angestellter Mensch bekommt Gehalt.

> Angestellte fühlen sich weniger frei als Selbständige.
>
> Die Angestellten haben sich organisiert.
>
> Ein Angestellter bekommt Gehalt.

Answer (score 0):

Es gibt tatsächlich Wörter, die mehrere Plurale (ist das der Plural von *Plural*?) haben, wenn auch die in der Frage angeführten Beispiele nicht darunter sind. Entweder sind die dazugehörigen Singular-Formen Homonyme (Wörter, die zwar gleich lauten, aber unterschiedliche Bedeutungen haben), die dann im Plural "getrennte Wege gehen":

> Tempo - Tempos (in der Bedeutung "Geschwindigkeit(en)")
> Tempo - Tempi (in der Bedeutung "Zug/Züge beim Schwimmen")

Daneben gibt es einige Wörter, bei denen quasi Uneinigkeit besteht, was denn der Plural sein sollte. Allerdings hat in dem Beispiel die erste Form der zweiten anscheinend den Rang abgelaufen und ist deutlich häufiger:

> Bösewicht - *Bösewichte*
> Bösewicht - *Bösewichter*

Während etwa Wilhelm Busch in "Max und Moritz" noch reimt "... in den Trichter schüttelt er die *Bösewichter* ...".

Außerdem gibt es Wörter (meist Fremdwörter), die den Plural sowohl nach der deutschen wie auch der Originalsprache bilden, beides nebeneinander im Gebrauch:

> Aroma - *Aromen* - *Aromata* (aber auch *Aromas*)
> Konto - *Kontos* - *Konten*